# What are like buttons on YouTube made?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'd like to know, how can I make this effect like on YouTube.
I mean, when I hover over the button it gets darker, and when I click it changes color to blue.
Is this a pure CSS or there is a JavaScript too? (Only front-end of course).

And what type of icons should I use?

Comment: Right click on the button and inspect in the dev tools. First thing you need to learn as a web dev.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Actually I wouldn't ask if I knew that from inspecting.

Answer (score 3):

This effect can be easily done with CSS Pseudoclasses

With these you can control the style of an element when the pointer is over it, click on it, etc.

An example in **.css** file:

```css
/ * unvisited link * /
a: link {
  color: # FF0000;
}

/ * visited link * /
a: visited {
  color: # 00FF00;
}

/ * mouse over link * /
a: hover {
  color: # FF00FF;
}

/ * selected link * /
a: active {
  color: # 0000FF;
}
```

Here is a reference link to more information about pseudoclasses

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: And this "like" button has to be a .svg, .png or some Unicode?

Comment: For icons, the best option would be to work with .svg, they are responsive and light.
To make it more dinamic, for example, you could put that .svg in a <div> element and use the css pseudoclasses to make it change color (or .svg if desired) depending on the action.

Answer (score 2):

can be both, but of course you can make in pure css

thats an edit on coment, but i made one to you see

```css
            #button {
                cursor: pointer;
                color: rgb(100, 98, 98);
                border: none;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
            }

            #button:hover {
                background: rgb(66, 65, 65);
                outline: none;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>hover css</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="submit" id="button">Press here!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dark effect on hover can be made with CSS pseudo-selector `:hover`. The colour change to blue on click depends on your need. If you want the colour to change blue on click and again turn red when mouse is released, CSS pseudo-selector `:active` can be used. But if you want the colour to permanently change to blue and not turn red after mouse is released, javascript may be used.

1: With `:active`:

```css
.myButton{
  padding: 20px;
  font-size:24px;
  background-color: #ff6347;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.myButton:hover{
  background-color: #8b0000;
}

.myButton:active{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">Click me</button>
```

2: With javascript:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".myButton");

function hover(){
  button.style.backgroundColor = "#8b0000";
}

function click(){
  button.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

function hoverOut(){
  button.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

button.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);

button.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOut);

button.addEventListener("click", click);
```

```css
.myButton{
  padding: 20px;
  font-size:24px;
  background-color: #ff6347;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">Click me</button>
```

It's up to you which method to use.